# Guess fitting Voigt curve to data - Python script behaves erratically

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, lmfit

Let me describe what I'm attempting to do. This requires the eyes of somebody more knowledgable of Python than myself.

I have a set of data (actually sediment diameter vs. percentage in a sample) and when plotted it shows a unique spectrum. I'm assuming that there are "modes" hidden within the data, and am trying to force fit voigt, guassian or lorentzian curves so draw out some information. The framework of this script came from a person doing a similar thing on XRD data. I'm not quite proficient enough to really *understand* how the script is achieving the goals, so I'm having trouble isolating a few strange behaviors. Let me outline the weirdness first, then I'll share the code.

1. If I run the code over and over again with the same data, the results are not always the same. Not only that, but maybe 25% of the time, I get an error that I can't figure out. Why does this error happen, and why is it only happening some of the time?

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'

2. When I define "spec" in the beginning of the code, I have to specifc model types. By chance, I tried VoigtModel first, and again, it works most of the time. However, if I specify a type to Gaussian or Lorentzian the script doesn't run at all:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

3. In the script, I ask it to print some information regarding the curves that it fit. Specifically, the x, y values of the peak of the curve. However, when I run it subsequent times, it may fit different curves but the print() output doesn't change. Like, what?

If anybody could give the code a try and perhaps offer some insight as to what's wonky about this code, I'd be hugely grateful.

**edit** I've discovered that if I add more {'type': 'VoigtModel'} to spec = , the frequency of script failure decreases. If I remove some (leave one or two) then it fails at a much greater percentage. Still could use some help understanding the connection.

The code:

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import random

from lmfit import models

x = 0, 0.09326263, 0.186541806, 0.279826296, 0.373096863, 0.466372043, 0.559644359, 0.652910952, 0.746190193, 0.839463682, 0.932734784, 1.026014714, 1.119288717, 1.212558343, 1.305836463, 1.399111865, 1.492381488, 1.585657384, 1.678931325, 1.772207061, 1.865478378, 1.958752334, 2.05202538, 2.145299504, 2.238574433, 2.331847735, 2.425123471, 2.518395825, 2.611671451, 2.704945386, 2.798218396, 2.891491964, 2.984766114, 3.078040106, 3.171314505, 3.264585057, 3.357863555, 3.451137678, 3.544409886, 3.637684839, 3.730956661, 3.824229504, 3.917507936, 4.010781777, 4.104055591, 4.197326, 4.290603266, 4.383874926, 4.477149297, 4.57042345, 4.663698494, 4.756972396, 4.850245469, 4.943519232, 5.036793499, 5.13006734, 5.223340556, 5.316615186, 5.409888929, 5.503163537, 5.596438512, 5.689708905, 5.782986369, 5.876257098, 5.969532028, 6.062807987, 6.156078156, 6.249352461, 6.342627453, 6.43590194, 6.529177933, 6.622450379, 6.715725752, 6.808997914, 6.902272777, 6.995546352, 7.088819796, 7.18209372, 7.275367937, 7.36864248, 7.461916216, 7.555189618, 7.648464489, 7.741737739, 7.835015624, 7.928288902, 8.021559911, 8.114833257, 8.208110415, 8.301378965, 8.394658258, 8.487929146, 8.581205011, 8.674478952, 8.767749555, 8.861024001, 8.954299075, 9.047574353, 9.140848269, 9.234120373, 9.327394253, 9.420668151, 9.513942544, 9.607217038, 9.700491238, 9.793764758, 9.887039268, 9.980313168, 10.0735868, 10.16686092, 10.26013875, 10.35340805, 10.44668356, 10.53995856, 10.63323182, 10.72650553
y = 0.001352, 0.001721, 0.002661, 0.00523, 0.010879, 0.020142, 0.030427, 0.039188, 0.046922, 0.055438, 0.065352, 0.076432, 0.089913, 0.107888, 0.132296, 0.164797, 0.208043, 0.266067, 0.343688, 0.443698, 0.565158, 0.704086, 0.854979, 1.01437, 1.17932, 1.34739, 1.51366, 1.67215, 1.81638, 1.94147, 2.0432, 2.11934, 2.16792, 2.19005, 2.18907, 2.17172, 2.14565, 2.11866, 2.09749, 2.08736, 2.09102, 2.1084, 2.13739, 2.17478, 2.21729, 2.26139, 2.30342, 2.33966, 2.36671, 2.38045, 2.37413, 2.33769, 2.26088, 2.13908, 1.9769, 1.78619, 1.57832, 1.35944, 1.13483, 0.919488, 0.743312, 0.637312, 0.615423, 0.665356, 0.744581, 0.78791, 0.743882, 0.617121, 0.46602, 0.356204, 0.320677, 0.361725, 0.45788, 0.566712, 0.650727, 0.701846, 0.739237, 0.788714, 0.863346, 0.956347, 1.04314, 1.09353, 1.0874, 1.02493, 0.925497, 0.815472, 0.721377, 0.658056, 0.628985, 0.623906, 0.617012, 0.578717, 0.487132, 0.346259, 0.185964, 0.066494, 0.011942, 0.000815, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
#xlog = [math.log(xval) for xval in x]

spec = {
    'x': x,
    'y': y,
    'model': [
        {'type': 'VoigtModel'},
        {'type': 'VoigtModel'},
        {'type': 'VoigtModel'},
        {'type': 'VoigtModel'},
    ]}

plt.plot(spec['x'], spec['y'])
plt.show()


def update_spec_from_peaks(spec, model_indicies, peak_widths=(1, 50), **kwargs):
    x = spec['x']
    y = spec['y']
    x_range = np.max(x) - np.min(x)
    peak_indicies = signal.find_peaks_cwt(y, peak_widths)
    np.random.shuffle(peak_indicies)
    for peak_indicie, model_indicie in zip(peak_indicies.tolist(), model_indicies):
        model = spec['model'][model_indicie]
        if model['type'] in ['GaussianModel', 'LorentzianModel', 'VoigtModel']:
            params = {
                'height': y[peak_indicie],
                'sigma': x_range / len(x) * np.min(peak_widths),
                'center': x[peak_indicie]
            }
            if 'params' in model:
                model.update(params)
            else:
                model['params'] = params
    return peak_indicies

# 
peaks_found = update_spec_from_peaks(spec, [0], peak_widths=(5,))    
print(peaks_found)

for i in peaks_found:
 print(x[i], y[i])


def generate_model(spec):
    composite_model = None
    params = None
    x = spec['x']
    y = spec['y']
    x_min = np.min(x)
    x_max = np.max(x)
    x_range = x_max - x_min
    y_max = np.max(y)
    for i, basis_func in enumerate(spec['model']):
        prefix = f'm{i}_'
        model = getattr(models, basis_func['type'])(prefix=prefix)
        if basis_func['type'] in ['GaussianModel', 'LorentzianModel', 'VoigtModel']: # for now VoigtModel has gamma constrained to sigma
            model.set_param_hint('sigma', min=1e-6, max=x_range)
            model.set_param_hint('center', min=x_min, max=x_max)
            model.set_param_hint('height', min=1e-6, max=1.1*y_max)
            model.set_param_hint('amplitude', min=1e-6)
            # default guess is horrible!! do not use guess()
            default_params = {
                prefix+'center': x_min + x_range * random.random(),
                prefix+'height': y_max * random.random(),
                prefix+'sigma': x_range * random.random()
            }
        else:
            raise NotImplemented(f'model {basis_func["type"]} not implemented yet')
        if 'help' in basis_func:  # allow override of settings in parameter
            for param, options in basis_func['help'].items():
                model.set_param_hint(param, **options)
        model_params = model.make_params(**default_params, **basis_func.get('params', {}))
        if params is None:
            params = model_params
        else:
            params.update(model_params)
        if composite_model is None:
            composite_model = model
        else:
            composite_model = composite_model + model
    return composite_model, params


model, params = generate_model(spec)
output = model.fit(spec['y'], params, x=spec['x'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(spec['x'], spec['y'], s=4)
components = output.eval_components(x=spec['x'])
print(len(spec['model']))
for i, model in enumerate(spec['model']):
    ax.plot(spec['x'], components[f'm{i}_'])```
````

Answer (score 1):

It should be sort of obvious that any code will run exactly the same ***every single time*** when given the same inputs.

The fitting appears to behave erratically because you are deliberately giving erratic data.  Really, you *are* telling it to randomize the initial starting values. And you are setting bounds programmatically, and not checking how close the initial values are to the bounds.  So, ask yourself, why are you doing these things?

Your code seems quite complicated, possibly so much so that you don't understand it. Start by getting rid of all the junk.  Maybe make a model that is a sum of Gaussians, maybe something like this (code will run, give a decent fit):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

from lmfit import models

x = np.array([0, 0.09326263, 0.186541806, 0.279826296, 0.373096863, 0.466372043, 0.559644359, 0.652910952, 0.746190193, 0.839463682, 0.932734784, 1.026014714, 1.119288717, 1.212558343, 1.305836463, 1.399111865, 1.492381488, 1.585657384, 1.678931325, 1.772207061, 1.865478378, 1.958752334, 2.05202538, 2.145299504, 2.238574433, 2.331847735, 2.425123471, 2.518395825, 2.611671451, 2.704945386, 2.798218396, 2.891491964, 2.984766114, 3.078040106, 3.171314505, 3.264585057, 3.357863555, 3.451137678, 3.544409886, 3.637684839, 3.730956661, 3.824229504, 3.917507936, 4.010781777, 4.104055591, 4.197326, 4.290603266, 4.383874926, 4.477149297, 4.57042345, 4.663698494, 4.756972396, 4.850245469, 4.943519232, 5.036793499, 5.13006734, 5.223340556, 5.316615186, 5.409888929, 5.503163537, 5.596438512, 5.689708905, 5.782986369, 5.876257098, 5.969532028, 6.062807987, 6.156078156, 6.249352461, 6.342627453, 6.43590194, 6.529177933, 6.622450379, 6.715725752, 6.808997914, 6.902272777, 6.995546352, 7.088819796, 7.18209372, 7.275367937, 7.36864248, 7.461916216, 7.555189618, 7.648464489, 7.741737739, 7.835015624, 7.928288902, 8.021559911, 8.114833257, 8.208110415, 8.301378965, 8.394658258, 8.487929146, 8.581205011, 8.674478952, 8.767749555, 8.861024001, 8.954299075, 9.047574353, 9.140848269, 9.234120373, 9.327394253, 9.420668151, 9.513942544, 9.607217038, 9.700491238, 9.793764758, 9.887039268, 9.980313168, 10.0735868, 10.16686092, 10.26013875, 10.35340805, 10.44668356, 10.53995856, 10.63323182, 10.72650553])

y = np.array([0.001352, 0.001721, 0.002661, 0.00523, 0.010879, 0.020142, 0.030427, 0.039188, 0.046922, 0.055438, 0.065352, 0.076432, 0.089913, 0.107888, 0.132296, 0.164797, 0.208043, 0.266067, 0.343688, 0.443698, 0.565158, 0.704086, 0.854979, 1.01437, 1.17932, 1.34739, 1.51366, 1.67215, 1.81638, 1.94147, 2.0432, 2.11934, 2.16792, 2.19005, 2.18907, 2.17172, 2.14565, 2.11866, 2.09749, 2.08736, 2.09102, 2.1084, 2.13739, 2.17478, 2.21729, 2.26139, 2.30342, 2.33966, 2.36671, 2.38045, 2.37413, 2.33769, 2.26088, 2.13908, 1.9769, 1.78619, 1.57832, 1.35944, 1.13483, 0.919488, 0.743312, 0.637312, 0.615423, 0.665356, 0.744581, 0.78791, 0.743882, 0.617121, 0.46602, 0.356204, 0.320677, 0.361725, 0.45788, 0.566712, 0.650727, 0.701846, 0.739237, 0.788714, 0.863346, 0.956347, 1.04314, 1.09353, 1.0874, 1.02493, 0.925497, 0.815472, 0.721377, 0.658056, 0.628985, 0.623906, 0.617012, 0.578717, 0.487132, 0.346259, 0.185964, 0.066494, 0.011942, 0.000815, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])


peaks = signal.find_peaks_cwt(y, (1.5, 25))             
xstep = x.ptp() / len(x)

model, params = None, None

for i, peak_index in enumerate(peaks):
    this_model = models.GaussianModel(prefix=f'p{1+i:d}_')
    this_params = this_model.make_params(amplitude=y[peak_index], center=x[peak_index], sigma=2*xstep)
    if model is None:
        model = this_model
        params = this_params
    else:
        model += this_model
        params.update(this_params)
        
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Does it need to be a lot more complicated than that?  Hm, maybe not.   This gives a decent fit, though it might be missing a subtle shoulder peak at around x=7.

Start simple.  Keep it simple for as long as possible.  Add complexity only when it simplifies something else.

Comment: You're absolutely correct: I'm very much a novice at anything beyond data visualizations and I didn't truly understand what it was doing and how. This simplified code does appear to be achieving all that I was hoping, and is much more manageable. I believe this is something I can work on. Thanks very much.